# Is there any notation for testing if A is in B?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

I want to do a union over sets $A_i$, but only if $A_i \in B_i$. I don't know any way to write this concisely. I was trying to write something with unions and intersections but I can never get it to exclude $A_i$ if it's not entirely contained in the corresponding $B_i$

Comment: Do you mean that $B$ is a set of sets, and you want to union only the sets that are in it? (e.g. $B = \{\{1\}, \{2, 4, 6\}, \{-1, -2, -3\}\}$). Or is B a set containing similar elements to A, and you want to union the ones where A is a subset of B? Because that's a different notation.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like: $$\bigcup\limits_{i:A_i \in B_i}A_i$$

Answer (score 1):

You've already written it. One way of writing the overall expression would be: $$\bigcup\{A_i\mid i\in I \land A_i\in B_i\}$$

Answer (score 0):

You could define indicator functions on sets: 
$$
A\cdot 1_{\text{statement}} =
\begin{cases}
A & 1_{\text{statement}}=1\\ 
\emptyset & 1_{\text{statement}}=0\ 
\end{cases}
$$
And then Union over all the sets times the indicator functions.